# Problem loading custom template tags (Error: No module named x)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I am currently writing a few custom template tags but for some reason they will not load. My directory structure is as follows:

```
MyProj
 |
 ----MyApp
     |
     |----templatetags
          |
          |----myapp_tags.py
          |----__init__.py
```

**In myapp_tags.py**

```
from django.template import Library, Node
from myproj.myapp.models import Product

register = Library()

class LatestProductsNode(Node):
    def render(self, context):
        context['recent_products'] = Product.objects.all()[:5]
        return ''

def get_latest_products(parser, token):
    return LatestProductsNode()

get_latest_products = register.tag(get_latest_products)
```

**In settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'myproj.myapp',
)
```

**In the Template**

```
{% load myapp_tags %}
```

**The error i get when trying to load the page:**

```
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError Exception Value:    

'myapp_tags' is not a valid tag library: Could not load template library from django.templatetags.myapp_tags, No module named myapp_tags
```

Comment: you could check [this][1] having more details that will help you 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607544/django-could-not-load-template-tag/21588173#21588173

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in *settings.py*, you should never name the project 'myproj' explicitely. In `INSTALLED_APPS`, just use 'myapp'. Also, you should have this :

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)
```

And be sure to have an `__init__.py` in the `myapp` folder as well as in `templatetags`.

Use `manage.py shell` then `from myapp.templatetags import myapp_tags` to find out if theres any python error in the *myapp_tags.py* file.

Also, be sure that *myapp_tags.py* file name doesnt conflicts with another folder/file in your project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 - You just saved my computer from an air born trip across my office. Appreciated.

Comment: Is this still relevant for Django 1.8?

Comment: @Pureferret for Django 1.8 take a look at this :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/  you need to add template directories in your settings.  I just ran into into this.

Answer (score 16):

One thing that's tripped me up is that the [magic importing of templatetags](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/dec/04/magic-tags/) bypasses the automatic reloading of the development server.
If the following works in `manage.py shell`

```
>>> from django.templatetags import myapp_tags
>>>
```

Then everything is actually working and you just need to reload the development server.  If on the other hand you get an `ImportError` then something is wrong and you should check your `INSTALLED_APPS`, that you have an *__init__.py* file in the templatetags directory and all the other things suggested in the other answers.

This will probably only apply to a tiny fraction of the people who experience template tag loading problems, but this is the second time I've arrived at this question in as many weeks and both times it's just taken restarting the development server to get things working.

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue - was pulling my hair out!

Comment: Please, vote this one thousand times, this was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons:

1. due to error in templatetgs code.
2. If you have used model import in templatetags

For #2, for example. If you are doing:

```
from your_app2.models import model
```

This will go wrong, so instead above, you should do

```
from your_project.your_app2.models import model
```

It worked me this way.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem in Django 2 and realized that the custom template tag files must have unique names across all of your project apps.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that `nyapp_tags` is not at the top level of an installed project.  If you put `myproj.myapp.templatetags` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, you should be fine.

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` is not `sys.path`, `myproj.myapp.templatetags` is not valid app.

Comment: Hi, This seems to work. Though is this a bug? or is this how it's supposed to work? From the documentation i understand that django loops through installed apps and looks for a directory called 'templatetags' within any of the installed apps. Therefore you should not have to specifically add this!

Comment: Issy, you're correct. You shouldn't put the templatetags folder on the python path. Often if the template tag can't be found, there's an import error occurring - but it doesn't seem obvious from your code (perhaps a circular import?)