# Django could not load template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have created a `templatetags` folder inside my application and inside a file named `posts.py`, I have written the following code;

```
from django.template import Library, Node
from advancedviews.models import Post
register = Library()
class AllPost(Node):
    def render(self,context):
        context['all_posts'] =  Post.objects.all()
        return ''
def get_all_posts(parser,token):
    return AllPost()
get_all_posts = register.tag(get_all_posts)
```

Now, I try to load this template tag inside my template;

```
{% load get_all_posts %}
```

But this gives me with error, `'get_all_posts' is not a valid tag library: Template library get_all_posts not found, tried django.templatetags.get_all_posts,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.get_all_posts`

What is the error in this template or have I missed something here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `load` you need to use the name of the library, not the tag - so `posts` in your case.

(I assume you also have a blank `__init__.py` in the templatetags directory, and that the application is in `INSTALLED_APPS`).

Comment: Well I edited the the code as above but still it gives me the same error.

Comment: I found out my mistake, I was just loading the file with wrong name. Now, I successfully loaded the tag as {% load posts %} adn then load the function as {% get_all_posts %}. Now, I could use all the context variables. Is it how it is to be done ?

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have the following structure:

```
-- Application_Name

-------templatetags

--------------__init__.py

--------------templates_extras.py

-------__init__.py

-------settings.py

-- manage.py
```

You have to make sure of the following:

- your application itself inside which your "templatetags" is resident is actually installed in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py (e.g. "Application_Name")
- your tag module itself that exists inside "templatetags" is already installed in INSTALLED_APP in settings.py (e.g. "ApplicationName.templatetags.tempaltes_extras")
- keep sure you have "`__init__.py`" under templatetags directory
- you have to restart the server
- In some cases you have to remove all generated *.pyc if it did not work then retry again

Comment: Removing the old `*.pyc` files solved my issue. Thanks!