# django custom template tag - import model blog error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to import a model class called `BlogDetails` to use in my customised template tags page.

Here is the structure of my app:

```
appname (directory)
  -->core (directory)
    -->models.py (file)
    -->templatetags (directory)
      -->customised_template_tags.py (file)
```

Here is the import statements in the `customised_template_tags.py` file. This is the same structure of other import statements I have used in my view files:

```
import datetime
import os

from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from django.templatetags.static import static
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation.trans_real import gettext

from appname.common.utils import get_supported_language_code
from appname.core.models import BlogDetails

register = template.Library()
```

Here is the import statement on the `models.py` file **at line 76** (refered to in the error message)  that imports code from the `customised_template_tags.py` file:

```
from appname.core.templatetags.customised_template_tags import absolute_static, alternative_file, \
    file_url
```

Here is the error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\desktop\appname\appname\core\models.py", line 76, in <module>
    from appname.core.templatetags.customised_template_tags import absolute_static, alternative_file, \
  File "C:\Users\me\desktop\appname\appname\core\templatetags\customised_template_tags.py", line 11, in <module>
    from appname.core.models import BlogDetails
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlogDetails'
```

I have re-started my development server and I have read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483927/problem-loading-custom-template-tags-error-no-module-named-x) and followed the suggestions in the answer and I have also read the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/).

**Can anyone suggest the solution to my issue?**

Comment: is it a Django app or just a directory? Is there an model called BlogDetails inside your `models.py`? Is there an `__init__.py` in your `core` directory?

Comment: It is an app and there is a model class called `BlogDetails` in the `models.py` file. and there is a `__init.py__` file in the `core` directory.

Comment: Your traceback looks inconsistent. You have `from myapp.core.templatetags` which does not match `from myapp.core.templatetags.` Using made up names makes it trickier to help, as you may be hiding the real problem. Please show the full traceback. Which file is your import `from myapp.core.templatetags.customised_template_tags` in?

Comment: Yes I have renamed the appname in the traceback and fixed the typo. The line of code `from appname.core.templatetags.customised_template_tags import absolute_static, alternative_file, file_url` is located in the `models.py` file.

Comment: Python 2 or 3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do a circular import:

1. `appname.core.models` tries to import `appname.core.templatetags.customised_template_tags`
2. `appname.core.templatetags.customised_template_tags` tries to import `appname.core.models`
3. Because `appname.core.models` hasn't finished to load, it can't be imported, so it fails.

A quick fix:

Import your model inside your tag function.
Or the opposite, import your tag only in the function where you use it.